# Get data from data-price using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a working code where i output the price using value="" but i need a way to get data from data-price="" so that i can use value="" to store SKUs.
Working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pe2gpp01/21/

What does this code do? It returns fixed price for female for all products. Price changes for Male only.

```
<div>
<label class="product">Product</label>
<span>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="10" >
<label>Product A</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="20" checked>
<label>Product B</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="30">
<label>Product C</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="40" >
<label>Product D</label>
</span></div>

<div>
<label class="gender">Gender</label>
<span>
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" checked>
<label>Male</label>
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="female">
<label>Female</label>
</span></div>

<span>Show Price: <span id="price"></span></span>


<script>
$(function() {
$('[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

    var price = $('[value="female"]')[0].checked
      ? 10 
      : $('[name="category"]:checked').val();
   $('#price').text(price);
}).change();
});

</script>
```

I need data from this

```
<input name="category" type="radio" value="SKU001" data-price="10">
<label>Product A</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="SKU002" data-price="20" checked>
<label>Product B</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="SKU003" data-price="30">
<label>Product C</label>
<input name="category" type="radio" value="SKU004" data-price="40">
<label>Product D</label>
```

Comment: You are not using data-price in the HTML code anywhere.

Comment: i updated the post. anyway i got the answer. thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get `data-price` attribute

```
$('[name="category"]:checked').data('price')
```

Comment: This in my opinion makes more sense than the other solutions (others used parseInt which would create rounding errors).

Answer (score 0):

This code is saying **if** you have a value female element checked, then set the price to 10, otherwise price is the value in named category.

```
 var price = $('[value="female"]')[0].checked
      ? 10 
      : $('[name="category"]:checked').val();
```

... so, this ...

```
    var price = $('[value="female"]')[0].checked
      ? 10 + parseInt($('[name="category"]:checked').val(),10)
      : $('[name="category"]:checked').val();
```

... will add 10 to the category value (note the user of the parseInt function for proper addition.